# Javascript Validation

Tags: php, javascript

I was just trying to submit a simple form to the same page but when it is submitted it will call PHP function on the same page. However I was trying to do some JavaScript validation before submission. So I want to know what the difference between using onSubmit call js function in the form tag and onClick call js function with button.... This is what I am currently trying to do.

```
<?php
  function tobecalled()
  {
    echo "This was run";
  }
?>
<html>
  <head><title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testResults (form) 
    {
      var TestVar = form.inputboxname.value;
      if(TestVar == '')
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" onSubmit="return testResults(this);">
      <input type="text" name="inputboxname" />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      tobecalled();
      ?>
    </form>
  </body
</html>
```

It works..

But if I make (Submit Via JS)

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" onClick="return testResults(this);"/>
  ...
```

Its still calls the PHP function `tobecalled()`--Why? I am expecting it not call. How do it work?

Comment: You will get better responses with nicely formatted code and a well written question.

Comment: I have put the complete working code..Fine to rephrase what is the difference between using onSubmit in form and onClick with a button...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because regardless of whether you add your javascript to the onsubmit of the form or the onclick of the submit button the form will still be submitted by the submit button. That means that a request is being sent back to the server and $_POST['submit'] will be set. Since that variable is set you find your function being called.

Comment: Oh Ok..Thanks That was very helpful..So all the Js Validation has to be done by onSubmit in the form tag..At least most of the times I presume...

Comment: That would be preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Actually that is not correct.  If the onClick returned False then the submit wouldn't happen.

Comment: @David McEwing The point I am trying to make is that as long as the form is submitted, the server side function will be called. That is not controlled by where the javascript is placed.

Comment: The question is "why is it called" while your point is correct and the reason it was called is because the form was submitted the reason it was submitted and the PHP code called was because the JavaScript event handlers didn't prevent the submission of the form by returning false.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it is allowing it to go through is because you are passing `this` in the onclick event.  In this instance `this` is referring to the submit button not the form as required by the function.

Thus `form.inputboxname.value` returns `undefined` which is not '' (empty string) and therefore the `testResults` function returns true.  So the submit is then activated.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is `this`.  `this` points to a different object in `onClick` than in `onSubmit`.  Your function expects a form to be passed, but when you use onClick, you give it the submit button.  That's why the second method doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Oh Ok..Thanks That was very helpful..So all the Js Validation has to be done by onSubmit in the form tag..At least most of the times I presume...

Comment: That would be recommeded in general but not always the case as depending on the button being clicked may require different parts of the form to be validated or alternately not validated at all.